# Find the limit $\lim_{t \to 9} \frac{3-\sqrt{t}}{9-t}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Find the limit $$\lim_{t \to 9} \frac{3-\sqrt{t}}{9-t}$$
Here's what I have done:
 $$\lim_{t \to 9} \frac{3-\sqrt{t}}{9-t} \\ =   \frac{3-\sqrt{t}}{9-t} \cdot \frac{3+\sqrt{t}}{3+\sqrt{t}} \\ =\frac {9-t^2}{(9-t)(3+\sqrt{t})}$$ 
What next?

Comment: $\lim_{t \to 9} \frac{3-\sqrt{t}}{9-t} \\ =   \frac{3-\sqrt{t}}{9-t} \cdot \frac{3+\sqrt{t}}{3+\sqrt{t}} \\ =\frac {9-\sqrt{t}^2}{(9-t)(3+\sqrt{t})}$

Comment: Hunh, I guess people pounced on this one.

Comment: @BrianTung indeed, even people with huge amounts of rep. :(

Comment: @TheCount: Well, in my defense, when I posted my answer, there was no other answer!  (I might have guessed, I concede, that there would be.)

Comment: @BrianTung haha, no ill will, my friend. but you guys are so quick around here! i'm dyin'!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim _{ t\to 9 } \frac { 3-\sqrt { t }  }{ 9-t } =\lim _{ t\to 9 } \frac { 3-\sqrt { t }  }{ \left( 3-\sqrt { t }  \right) \left( 3+\sqrt { t }  \right)  } =\lim _{ t\to 9 } \frac { 1 }{ 3+\sqrt { t }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 6 } $$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $9-t=(3-\sqrt{t})(3+\sqrt{t})$

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you could do that!

Answer (score 2):

You're better off writing

$$
\lim_{t \to 9} \frac{3-\sqrt{t}}{9-t}
    = \lim_{t \to 9} \frac{3-\sqrt{t}}{(3-\sqrt{t})(3+\sqrt{t})}
$$

and moving on from there.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. You may rather write, as $t \to 9$,
$$
 \frac{3-\sqrt{t}}{9-t}= \frac{3-\sqrt{t}}{(3+\sqrt{t})(3-\sqrt{t})}= \frac1{3+\sqrt{t}}.
$$